# Find first match of a substring in a column of big data.table

Tags: r, regex, data.table, stringr

I have a big data table, where I want to check if a `103a_foo` is present. However, the filenames in a big table they are written differently, so I have to use regex.

```
dt = structure(list(myID = c("86577", "34005","34005", 
"194000", "30252", "71067"), 
filename = c("/scratch/tmpdir/12a_foo.mzXML.gz", 
"/scratch/tmpdir/103b_foo.XML.gz", "/scratch/tmpdir/103a_foo.XML.gz",
 "/scratch/tmpdir/103a_foo.XML.gz", 
"/scratch/tmpdir/100b_foo.XML.gz", "/scratch/tmpdir/108a_foo.XML.gz")),
 class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
.Names = c("myID", "filename"))
```

As an output, I want an index 3, as this is a first time it occurs. I would have used `grep('103a_foo', dt$filename)[1]`, but I want the search to stop at first occurrence as the table is large (10 million rows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `fixed = TRUE` it doesn't take that long. Is it really too slow for your needs?

```
x <- sample(dt$filename, 1e7, TRUE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(grep('103a_foo', x),
               grep('103a_foo',dt$filename, fixed = TRUE), 
               times = 5)

#Unit: milliseconds
#                              expr       min       lq      mean   #median        uq       max neval cld
#               grep("103a_foo", x) 2124.8178 2125.707 2128.7849 2127.542 2128.2054 2137.6532     5   b
# grep("103a_foo", x, fixed = TRUE)  826.2298  826.597  832.7058  829.969  840.1974  840.5359     5
```

To my knowledge, there is no efficient way to implement a `grep` that breaks out of the vectorization loop using pure R. You could use Rcpp, if you need this often.

Comment: I doubt `103a_foo` is a real regex OP is using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP doesn't provide any indication that she actually needs a regex. Based on her profile she might search for a specific sequence of the letters TACG.

Comment: See http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/ if you want to use Rcpp for this.

Comment: indeed, it's only 6 sec, which is OK. I just hoped I could combine `match`-like behaviour and regex in one command.

Answer (score 2):

As @Roland pointed out, with `grep` you won't be able to stop at the first match. However, if you need to do the operations you described often, it could be helpful to extract once and for all the "base names" you are about to look and then use `match` (which actually breaks at the first occurrence). Something like:

```
#this line might not work depending on the actual format of your real data
basenames<-gsub("^.*/|\\..*$","",dt$filename)
#then we use match
match("103a_foo",basenames)
#[1] 3
```